# How to access a textbox in a form from other form

Tags: c#

There are two forms, each one has a textbox. my question is

how to access the textbox on form 1 by form 2

and

how to access the textbox on form 2 by form 1?

I used

```
 Form1 ths;
 public Form2(Form1 my_form_1)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     ths = my_form_1;
 }
```

but I cannot access form2 from form1!!!

TQ

Comment: you should make the text box access modifier to public in order to gain access to it from other classess

Comment: You can pass `Form2` to `Form1` through property as well.

Comment: In the property of the textbox (or any control) make the "Modifiers" option to "Public".

Comment: Share a viewmodel between the 2 forms

Comment: What would you like to do with the textbox once you can access it?

Comment: from form1 change textbox1 from form2,, then results needs to be shown in textbox1 from form1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accessing the TextBox directly, you could share a ViewModel that offers the Properties you need to both Forms (or any other controls afterwards)

For this, you could create your own ViewModel using the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, that notifies any listeners that a property has changed. An example of such a class would be the following

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SimpleViewModel
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var local = PropertyChanged;
            if (local != null)
            {
                local.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected string result;
        public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                return result;
            }
            set
            {
                if (string.Equals(result, value))
                {
                    return;
                }
                result = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it's Result property would change, the class would notify any listeners that are registered to the PropertyChanged event of the class. The classes that listen to those changes can then choose how to handle or ignore this changed (eg, based on PropertyName) like such in Form2 (i called it ResultForm)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleViewModel
{
    public partial class ResultForm : Form
    {
        protected ViewModel viewModel;
        public ViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return viewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (object.Equals(ViewModel, value))
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (ViewModel != null)
                {
                    viewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnViewModelChanged;
                }
                viewModel = value;
                if (ViewModel != null)
                {
                    viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnViewModelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = sender as ViewModel;
            if (vm == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == "Result")
            {
                lblResult.Text = vm.Result;
            }
        }

        public ResultForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ResultForm(ViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel = null;
            base.OnClosed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we register to the PropertyChanged event when the ViewModel property is changed (or set by use of the constructor). When we get the property changed event, we check if it is indeed the "Result" property that changed, and if so, update our lblResult accordingly (could be your TextBox)

In form1 we could create the ViewModel, and this ViewModel is then given to the ResultForm, for sake of a testcase, i added it to the Form_Load event, although the important part here is simply that the ViewModel is the same for both forms (it could be a singleton class, ... depending on your need)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleViewModel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        protected ViewModel MyResultViewModel = new ViewModel();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResultForm form = new ResultForm(MyResultViewModel);
            form.Show();
            MyResultViewModel.Result = "42";
        }
    }
}
```

By setting the MyResultViewModel.Result property, the changes are send to the ResultForm and we see 42 in the Label

Comment: Thank you, I am trying it ;)

Comment: @SinaGilassi did it suit your needs?

Comment: I tried that code but from from2 i cannot change textbox1 in form1 !!! it is not two way

Comment: If you want it 2 way, you should also attach a listener for PropertyChanged on the ViewModel for Form1, and do the changes accordingly! I didn't only post a lot of code, i also posted a lot of explanation on what the code is doing and how you can replicate its behavior for other properties, other listeners

Comment: Many many thanks, you're right I considered the code as a base. I will try to add another listener for Form 1. you are great. Could you tell me which source is good for intermittent programmers? As the code you made, I have not seen in any books!! that is very interesting. which book do you suggest?

Comment: Now I encountered a new problem, how is the modelview activated in form1?! as the MyResultViewModel is already activated in form 2, I modify the codes but still have problem @Icepickle

Comment: in `public Form1()` after `InitializeComponent` you can attach yourself to the `PropertyChanged` event of the MyResultViewModel, and then inside the listener you should listen to the correct PropertyName that you wish to listen to, don't forget to detach the listener when the form closes or gets disposed

Comment: @SinaGilassi where could i see the changes? At the moment, i don't see any changes? If you have more questions about the code, you could also create a new question?

Comment: public Form1()

        {

            InitializeComponent();


            MyResultViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelChanged_2;

        }


        protected virtual void OnViewModelChanged_2(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)

        {

            var vm = sender as ViewModel;

            if (vm == null)

            {

                return;

            }

            if (e.PropertyName == "Result_2")

            {

                textBox1.Text = vm.Result_2;

            }

        }

Comment: @SinaGilassi Looks good to me ;)

Comment: it works and I a bit surprised with the EVENTs. very special connection between two forms through a class!

Comment: @SinaGilassi yes, events can be tricky at first, it takes some getting used to :) It is not such a special connection, this is a much taken approach to split concerns between presentation logic and data.

Comment: yes, I need to practice more and more ...

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the Instance of Form2 in Form1 you could just

```cs
public void yourMethod()
{
    Form2 form = new Form2(this);
    form.Show();
    form.textbox.Text = "xy";
}
```

Comment: then, I can change the value any time?